# while loop wont stop even when condition requires it to

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, boolean

My loop won't recognize that it needs to quit.
Any help is appreciated.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
    String name;
    int residentLoopNumber = 0;
    boolean ifResidentFound = false;
    boolean ifUserQuit;

    Resident[] residents = new Resident[6];
    residents[1] = new Resident("Kelly Ocean", "72", "female", "102", "C", false);
    residents[2] = new Resident("Sean White", "99", "male", "302", "A", true);
    residents[3] = new Resident("Elias Abiadal", "66", "male", "666", "A", true);
    residents[4] = new Resident("Terry Goldsmith", "94", "male", "471", "B", false);
    residents[5] = new Resident("Sarah Young", "90", "female", "111", "C", true);

    //prompting user to enter resident name
    System.out.print("Please enter a resident's name: ");
    name = kbd.nextLine();

    //checking if user entered exit keyword
    ifUserQuit = ifQuit(name);

    do {

        //checking if entered name matches any in the list.
        for (int i = 1; i < residents.length; ++i) {

            if (residents[i].getName().toLowerCase().equals(name.toLowerCase())) {

                residentLoopNumber = i;
                ifResidentFound = true;
            }
        }

        //loop prompting user to enter name again
        while (!ifResidentFound) {

            System.out.println("<" + name + ">" + " is not on record.");
            System.out.print("Please enter a resident's name: ");
            name = kbd.nextLine();
            ifUserQuit = ifQuit(name);
        }

        for (int i = 1; i < residents.length; ++i) {

            if (residents[i].getName().toLowerCase().equals(name.toLowerCase())) {

                residentLoopNumber = i;
                ifResidentFound = true;
            }
        }

        //displaying resident information
        System.out.print(residents[residentLoopNumber].toString());

    } while (!ifUserQuit);

}

public static boolean ifQuit(String input) {

    return input.toLowerCase().equals("exit");
}
```

}

my loop is supposed to end if user enters 'exit' 
but instead, I get this output when exit is entered. Any ideas?

Please enter a resident's name: exit
 is not on record.
Please enter a resident's name:

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing in the `while` loop that changes the condition variable. You need to set `ifResidentFound = true` at some point in the loop to exit it. It looks like you need to put your `for` loop inside your `while` loop.

Comment: my while loop is supposed to iterate in this condition `while (!ifUserQuit);`  and i have the line of code `ifUserQuit = ifQuit(name);` after every input which is supposed to update the value for 'ifUserQuit' which gets its value from a boolean method 'ifQuit(name)' which is set to return true if the user enters 'exit' @Mish

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding which loop isn't exiting here. The while loop inside the do loop is the one that will never exit. `ifResidentFound` is your condition and it will never change in that loop.

Comment: my while loop is not inside my for loop. my for loop ends before even displaying the output

Comment: what do you mean can explain that for me?

Comment: `ifResidentFound` has nothing to do with the loop for the program at all  it only checks if the user is found inside my array of objects

Comment: That check isn't executing because it isn't inside the input loop. You need to check the input against the residents array after every input.